# Core animation, self.presentationLayer() is nil

Tags: swift, core-animation

I have a swift custom CALayer that has a few dynamic (actually `@NSManaged` properties) I have everything set up correctly and the layers actionForKey is being called.

```
override public func actionForKey(key: String!) -> CAAction! {
    switch key {
    case "maxCircles", "numCircles":
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: key)
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear);
        animation.fromValue = self.presentationLayer().valueForKey(key);
        animation.duration = 0.2
        return animation;
    default:
        return super.actionForKey(key)
    }
}
```

Sometimes `self.presentationLayer().` throws an exception because it is implicitly unwrapped and is nil. In objective-C the code normally just does:

```
[[self presentationLayer] valueForKey:key]
```

Which doesn't crash but I never actually realised it could call though nil and generate 0 - which feels very wrong to me. There's no guarantee I'm animating from nil.

What's the right way to access `presentationLayer` in Swift? Should I test for nil? i.e.:

```
override public func actionForKey(key: String!) -> CAAction! {
    if ( key == "maxCircles" || key == "numCircles" ) && self.presentationLayer() != nil {

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: key)
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear);
        animation.fromValue = self.presentationLayer().valueForKey(key);
        animation.duration = 0.2
        return animation;
    }
    return super.actionForKey(key)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `presentationLayer` property returns an optional, so yes you should test for nil. In Objective-C messaging nil is a no-op and therefore won't cause your app to crash. Remember that safety is one of the primary goals of swift, so you will need to do your own checking here. If you write your function like this, it will work similarly to the Objective-C counterpart:

```
override public func actionForKey(key: String!) -> CAAction! {
    if key == "maxCircles" || key == "numCircles" {
        // Check your presentation layer first before doing anything else
        if let presoLayer = self.presentationLayer() as? CALayer {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: key)
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear);
            animation.fromValue = presoLayer.valueForKey(key);
            animation.duration = 0.2
            return animation;
        }
    }
    return super.actionForKey(key)
}
```

I'm assuming the rest of your code is right here and just answering the part about the optionality of `presentationLayer`. I switched your `switch` to an `if` because it seemed more readable to me.

Comment: This solution fixes the issue, but note that `presentationLayer()` returns an implicitly unwrapped optional, so users of this method shouldn't need to test for `nil`. (I would consider this a workaround for an Apple API bug.) That is, if it *can* be nil, it should return `AnyObject?`, not `AnyObject!`.

Comment: Matt Long's solution (and mine) are both workarounds for an Apple bug. It doesn't kill Objective-C apps because in Objective-C you can send a message to `nil` and nothing happens, but in Swift that's illegal.

Comment: AnyObject is not convertible to CALayer the correct test is `if self.presentationLayer() == nil` (added to answer)

Comment: "Matt Long's solution (and mine) are both workarounds for an Apple bug" @AaronBrager I hardly see this as a "bug"... If anything, it is the Objective-C behavior that's the bug.

Comment: @matt You don't see it as a bug that a method whose signature indicates it should return `AnyObject!` returns `nil`?

Comment: @AaronBrager No. On the contrary. The exclamation mark in `AnyObject!` _means_ "this might be nil". It is an Optional. If it couldn't return nil it wouldn't be an Optional.

Comment: It can also mean "it is clear from a program’s structure that an optional will always have a value" and "it can be safely assumed to have a value all of the time". I would expect `presentationLayer` to return a regular optional since neither of those statements are true for a presentation layer.

Comment: @RogerNolan You said "AnyObject is not convertible to CALayer". Was that an error message? I have functioning code that says otherwise. In my code I am accessing the presentation layer's position inside of the `if let` scope and it works perfectly.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes, but all you are saying here is that in their hand-tweaking of the APIs, Apple has evidently not come to revising the Swift API for CALayer yet. That is certainly something we can agree on. :) Until they do, all values are typed as IUOs and you should suspect the possibility of nil. And of course it is simply a fact that the presentation layer of a layer can be nil, namely because no animation of that layer is going on.

Comment: @matt I agree with you.

Comment: @AaronBrager Just to clarify, in case anyone is watching us argue this out: some day, all incoming values in Swift should be either non-optional or true optional - e.g., `AnyObject` or `AnyObject?`. Apple would like to get rid of all cases of `AnyObject!` (and other implicitly unwrapped optionals). I don't personally agree with this goal, but that's where they are headed and what they've been doing by hand-tweaking the APIs. But there are large areas of the APIs they haven't gotten to yet, and CALayer is one of them. — I hope I've stated our collective view correctly. :)

Comment: @matt I did see that error but retyping has made it go away, I'm either blaming a typo or my week old Swift. Probably the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Long's solution works. If you'd like to keep the `switch` syntax, though, you can just test for `nil` using the `case … where` syntax:

```
override func actionForKey(key: String!) -> CAAction! {
    switch key {
    case "maxCircles", "numCircles" where self.presentationLayer() != nil:
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: key)
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear);
        animation.fromValue = self.presentationLayer().valueForKey(key);
        animation.duration = 0.2
        return animation;
    default:
        return super.actionForKey(key)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just provide a default `fromValue` if there's no presentation layer:

```
animation.fromValue = self.presentationLayer() != nil ? self.presentationLayer().valueForKey(key) : 0;
```

Comment: Adding a default value is painful if the type is more complex - a colour say.

Comment: I agree - I'm just giving you options. You could also just set it to `nil` (see [Setting Interpolation Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004496-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3)).